# Populating a Combobox inside a Gridview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, combobox

i'm having a few problems working with a gridview and a combobox inside of it.

Here is the code for my ListView control:

```
<ListView Height="139" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,158,0,0" Name="lvAppointment" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" MinWidth="350">
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Appointment" Width="120">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=Appointment}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Type" Width="170">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ???/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Done" Width="50">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Done}" IsThreeState="False"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

I'm popluating the list from a sql ce database via c# with the following code

```
using (SqlCeCommand sqlCeAppointment = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT appid,appointment,done,apptype.type FROM appointment INNER JOIN apptype ON appointment.refatid = apptype.atid WHERE refeventid = @eventid;", sqlCeConn))
    {
        sqlCeAppointment.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventid", ((cListEventItem)lvEvent.SelectedItems[0]).id);
        using (SqlCeDataReader sqlCeAppointmentReader = sqlCeAppointment.ExecuteReader())
        {
            lvAppointment.Items.Clear();

            while (sqlCeAppointmentReader.Read())
            {
                lvAppointment.Items.Add(new cListAppointmentItem { id = sqlCeAppointmentReader.GetGuid(sqlCeTerminReader.GetOrdinal("appid")), Appointment = sqlCeAppointmentReader.GetDateTime(sqlCeTerminReader.GetOrdinal("appointment")), Type = sqlCeAppointmentReader.GetString(sqlCeTerminReader.GetOrdinal("type")), Done = sqlCeAppointmentReader.GetByte(sqlCeTerminReader.GetOrdinal("done")) });
            }
        }
    }
```

I can popluate the list just fine. But i want "Type" to be a combobox so the user can select the apropriate type of the appointment (its a list of appointments connected to an event). This combobox should be filled with data thats inside a table of the sql ce database (apptype). This table is not static, the users can add and delete items from this list.

I have tried a few ways i found via google, but failed. I guess i'm having problems understanding how this works/should work.

I hope someone can help me :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting a list of appointment-types on the MainViewModel. Then bind the `ItemsSource` of the `ComboBox` to that List and bind the `SelectedItem` to the AppointmentItem type.

```xml
<UserControl x:Name="TheUserControl">
    <ListView>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Type" Width="170">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=TheUserControl, Path=AppointmentTypes}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Type}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by defining a property of type ObservableCollection.
If the data type of the collection is string then you can define it as:

```
  public ObservableCollection<string> Types
        {
            get
            {
                ObservableCollection<string> _types = new ObservableCollection<string>();
                _types.Add("value1");
                _types.Add("value2");
                _types.Add("value3");
                return _types;
            }

        }
```

In your XAML you can bind it as:

```
 <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Types}" SelectedItem="{Binding MainViewModel.Type,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}"  Width="300"  ></ComboBox>
```